# Dynamics CRM 2013 Organization status Pending

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I was importing existing organization in CRM 2013 and my server restarted due to updates. 
When I logged in back to CRM server and open deployment manager, I see this organization but status is **Pending**. 
I am not able to delete this organization as well. 
What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Can you disable it? It might be best to redo the import into a new org.

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked on org which was in pending status. A pop up snap in loaded for sometime, when it disappeared, I see delete option on the right panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has never happened to me but I would delete the organization and recreate it.

If you are adventurous, you can always look into the database in mscrm_config.dbo.organization to change the status yourself. This is the table behind the deployment manager.

In any case, it's probably a non managed case by Microsoft.